# Database decision and schema design

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, cassandra, nosql

I'm trying to find a good database for my use-case, I'm not experienced in databases.
Here is my use-case: I need to acquire a lot of time series (ts) data with variable number of fields, one time series can have up to 50KB~100KB  and I can generate up to 100 ts/second. The requests to write the ts to the database will come from the local host from a c++ client. I will need to query the data from time to time (once every minute or so or on user request) and the queries can involve some filters on the data contents of the ts. Writing the data is more important and demanding than reading it. The c++ client will also receive images that will get stored on the file system and one image should be associated with one time series. Receiving the images will not happen all the time but when I have to receive them, the rate will be the same as the rate of ts, maximum 100 images/second. I can't do horizontal scaling by adding new nodes, my architecture is fixed so I'm not interested if one solution can scale linearly.

First I was thinking of Kafka that can replace my c++ client but then I was reading that kafka doesn't handle that well large files (one image can reach up to 10 MB). So a hybrid solution is needed where a c++ client will receive the images and the ts and stores images to disk and time series to a DB.
For databases I did some reading for the fallowing:

- Mongodb (16 mb limit per document)
- cassandra (need to design your columns very carefully by going from query to schema)
- influxdb (nice for ts)
- timescaleDB (SQL like schema optimized for ts, both influx and timescale seem to be faster and storing than cassandra)
- other nosql db ?

My time series have some fixed column names for which I know the data types and some column names that keep changing over time for which I don't know the data type beforehand. For example I can receive this ts for the first hour

```
fixed_col1 fixed_col2 ... fixed_colN     other_col1 other_col2
int         int           string            unknown   unknown
```

and the next hour I can receive the next ts

```
fixed_col1 fixed_col2 ... fixed_colN     other_col5 other_col6 other_col7
int        int            string           unknown   unknown   unknown
```

I don't mind if the other_cols are stored as blobs or jsons but some of the queries that I have to do from time to time will require that I parse the contents of the unknown columns and I would like, if possible, to keep all ts in the same table or document or logical unit.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations of software are not appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm more interested in a solution recommendation that can solve those requirements. I'm also not sure if there is an out of the box open source solution that can store this kind of data, I would like to know how to put together some open source solutions.